# How can I integrate SonarQube Quality Gate into my Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sonarqube, jenkins-groovy

I am executing in a pipeline a command to pass the sound of a project, what I need is that, just like in a normal job the sonar link remains once the job is executed, the same happens in the pipeline, now that when I run it in the pipeline, the SonarQube link is not saved, so I have the steps in groovy:

```
stage ('QA'){
  steps { 
     echo 'executing sonar'
     bat  'mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url='+env.SONAR_URL+' - 
     Dsonar.projectName=QA:%JOB_BASE_NAME% - 
     Dsonar.projectKey=QA:%JOB_BASE_NAME%'
  }
}

stage("Quality Gate"){
   timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') { // Just in case something goes wrong, pipeline will be killed after a timeout
       def qg = waitForQualityGate() // Reuse taskId previously collected by withSonarQubeEnv
       if (qg.status != 'OK') {
          error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing with:

```
stage ('QA'){
    steps {
        echo 'Running SonarQube..'
        withSonarQubeEnv('XXXXXXXX') {
            bat  'mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url='+env.SONAR_URL+' - 
            Dsonar.projectName=QA:%JOB_BASE_NAME% - 
            Dsonar.projectKey=QA:%JOB_BASE_NAME%'
            timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') {
                script {
                    def qg = waitForQualityGate()
                    if (qg.status != 'OK') {
                        error "Pipeline aborted due to a quality gate failure:   ${qg.status}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the XXXXXXXX should be replaced with the name of a Sonar config you've entered in Jenkins under Manage Jenkins>Configure System>SonarQube servers

Comment: Now I have the following issue: "Please use the 'withSonarQubeEnv' wrapper to run your analysis."

Comment: I've updated with a single stage example very similar to what we do.